# Create a table pivot-like output with SQL/Access

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have a table made of 2 columns:

```
Tested_Object | Result

     A        |  OK
     A        |  NOT OK
     A        |  NOT OK
     B        |  OK
```

And I need to have an output like the following:

```
Tested_Object | SUM    | OK    | NOT_OK

     A        |  3     |1      | 2 
     B        |  1     |1      | 0 (or empty)
```

I tried using:

```
SELECT
t1.Tested_Object,
Count(t1.Result) AS SUM,
Count(t2.Result) AS OK,
Count(t3.Result) AS NOT_OK
FROM
(t1 LEFT JOIN (t1 AS t2) ON t1.Tested_Object=t2.Tested_Object) 
LEFT JOIN (t1 AS t3) WHERE t1.Tested_Object=t3.Tested_Object 

GROUP BY t1.Tested_Object
```

now if I put:

```
WHERE (t2.Result="OK" AND t3.Result="NOT_OK")
```

or

```
WHERE (t2.Result="OK" OR t3.Result="NOT_OK")
```

or

```
t1 LEFT JOIN (t1 AS t2 WHERE t2.Result="OK") ON t1.Tested_Object=t2.Tested_Object
```

I get the same count number for each column or error.

I managed to get different columns numbers only saving all the OKs in a table and the NOT OKs in another table manually.. But I need a query that does the calculation completely automatically from input to output table.

If not clear, I'm a newbie with SQL :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MySQL Solution**:

You can make use of [**`CASE ... WHEN ... THEN`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case.html) to differentiate `OK` values from `NOT OK` values.

```
SELECT Tested_Object
     , COUNT( Tested_Object ) AS `SUM`
     , SUM( CASE WHEN Result = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS `OK`
     , SUM( CASE WHEN Result = 'NOT OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS `NOT_OK`
  FROM t1
 GROUP BY Tested_Object
```

**MS Access Solution**:

You can make use of [**`IIF Function`**](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3)

```
SELECT Tested_Object
     , COUNT( Tested_Object ) AS SUM
     , SUM( IIF( Result = 'OK', 1, 0 ) ) AS OK
     , SUM( IIF( Result = 'NOT OK', 1, 0 ) ) AS NOT_OK
  FROM t1
 GROUP BY Tested_Object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Tested_Object
 , count(*) SUM
 ,  Count(CASE
           WHEN Result = 'OK' THEN 1
         END) OK
 ,Count(CASE
           WHEN Result = 'NOT_OK' THEN 1
         END) NOTOK
FROM my_table 
GROUP 
BY Tested_Object;
```

Find solution in fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22986/1

Comment: MSAccess is returning syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'count(*) SUM'

Comment: @LuciaBelardinelli: It is for SQL not for MS Access

Comment: please see that in the subject there is Access word, also in the key.. thanks anyway